# How to identify continuity or discontinuity of an [Definite] integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can I figure out whether an improper integral converges based on the discontinuities in the integrand?
For instance, these two both have discontinuities within the intervals of integration, and the second one also involves infinity: $$\int_{-4}^{4}\frac{1}{x}dx$$
what about this one: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac {ln(x)}{x}dx$$
Thanks

Comment: Definite integrals are not functions, they're just numbers (if the integral exists) or nothing (if they do not). If you mean to ask if the integrand is continuous or not on the interval, that's a different question, if not, then there's no answer to your question, unless you mean to treat integrals that exist as the value they represent (i.e. as constant functions), in which case they're continuous everywhere.

Comment: @AdamHughes So should not we worry about continuity of the function we're integrating from?

Comment: The integrand (function you're integrating) needs to be considered as to whether the integral **exists**, but it's not about discontinuities "of the integral."

Do you mean to ask if the integrals *converge*? I.e. whether those two examples are actually numbers or not?

Comment: @AdamHughes So could you please tell me the steps to check before integrating whatever given to us?

Comment: @AdamHughes No, what I'm curious about is what if the integrand was not defined in a specific interval, what will happen then?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether the integral exists or not you need to treat them as limits around the discontinuities in the integrand.

The first one:

$$\int_{-4}^4{dx\over x}$$

exists iff **both** integrals:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-4}^t{dx\over x},\quad \lim_{s\to 0}\int_s^4{dx\over x}$$

exist. But just check out the second one, the FTC gives this as:

$$\lim_{s\to 0}\log 4-\log s\to\infty$$

Similarly for the second one you need that both limits:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^b{\ln x\over x}\,dx,\quad \lim_{s\to \infty}\int_b^s{\ln x\over x}\,dx$$

exist, but doing the first one and letting $u=\ln x\implies du={dx\over x}$ we are integrating

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{\log t}^{\log b}u\,du ={1\over 2}\log^2 b-{1\over 2}\log^2t\to \infty$$

so it also diverges. You could as easily check the second integral diverges as well, you can make the same $u$-substitution and get

$$\lim_{s\to \infty}{1\over 2}\left(\log^2 s-\log^2 b\right)\to\infty$$

but only one of them needs to fail to exist to guarantee the whole integral fails to exist.

Just by way of contrast, let's see that it **is** possible that discontinuities don't stop us from integrating. Take

$$\int_0^1{dx\over\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\int_t^1{dx\over x}$$

using the FTC we see this is:

$$\lim_{t\to 0}2\sqrt{1}-2\sqrt t=2$$